# in c++ how to shows result of matrix with the additions

Tags: c++, matrix, addition

i have following code, i want, my program takes inputs two matrix of size "3*3" and display results with additions. I'm confused, and don't know how to make it work.. please check my code and let me know how to deal with it.

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

const int maxRows = 3;
const int maxCols = 3;

void readMatrix(int arr[][maxCols]);
void displayMatrix(int a[][maxCols]);

int main() {

    int a[maxRows][maxCols];

    readMatrix(a);

    cout << "\n\n" << "The matrix is: " << '\n';

    displayMatrix(a);
}

void readMatrix(int arr[][maxCols]) {

    int row, col;
    for (row = 0; row < maxRows; row ++) {
        for(col=0; col < maxCols; col ++){
            cout << "\n" << "Enter " << row << ", " << col << " element: ";
            cin >> arr[row][col];
        }
        cout << '\n';
    }
}

void displayMatrix(int a[][maxCols]) {

    int row, col;
    for (row = 0; row < maxRows; row ++) {
        for(col = 0; col < maxCols; col ++) {
            cout << a[row][col] << '\t';
        }
        cout << '\n';
    }
}
```

Comment: You should provide the error details, if any and why you can not make it work.

Comment: Rakibul, i want my code takes inputs two matrix of size 3 * 3, and at the end display results with additions.

Comment: it shows the content already, do you mean addition of the content?

Comment: yes, it show simple matrix but i want addition, for ex for 1st array i enter 111... and second 222... and result will be 333 in results matrix

Comment: u have only one matrix, create another and write an `add` method to  create the addition matrix

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need a method to add

```
void add(int a[][maxCols], int b[][maxCols], int res[][maxCols])
{
 int row, col;

 for (row = 0; row < maxRows; row++) {
   for (col = 0; col < maxCols; col++) {
        res[row][col] = a[row][col] + b[row][col];  
    }   
  }
}
```

and create 2 matrix in `main`, add them and show the result:

```
int main() {

int a[maxRows][maxCols];
int b[maxRows][maxCols];
int result[maxRows][maxCols];

readMatrix(a);
readMatrix(b);


cout << "\n\n" << "The matrix is: " << '\n';
displayMatrix(a);
cout << "\n\n" << "The matrix is: " << '\n';
displayMatrix(b);

add(a, b, result);
cout << "\n\n" << "The  result matrix is: " << '\n';
displayMatrix(result);
}
```